# PropertyGrid with same childs and different nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I want my custom PropertyGrid with student1 and student2 as nodes with "Name,Section,Percentage,School" as childs for both nodes.
I tried like this :

```
class StudentClass
{
    private string name;
    private string section;
    private string percentage;
    private string school;

    [CategoryAttribute("Student1")]
    public string School
    {
        get { return school; }
        set { school = value; }
    }
    [CategoryAttribute("Student1")]
    public string Percentage
    {
        get { return percentage; }
        set { percentage = value; }
    }
    [CategoryAttribute("Student1")]
    public string Section
    {
        get { return section; }
        set { section = value; }
    }
    [CategoryAttribute("Student1")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private string name1;
    [CategoryAttribute("Student2")]
    public string Name1
    {
        get { return name1; }
        set { name1 = value; }
    }
    private string section1;
    [CategoryAttribute("Student2")]
    public string Section1
    {
        get { return section1; }
        set { section1 = value; }
    }
    private string percentage1;
    [CategoryAttribute("Student2")]
    public string Percentage1
    {
        get { return percentage1; }
        set { percentage1 = value; }
    }
    private string school1;
    [CategoryAttribute("Student2")]
    public string School1
    {
        get { return school1; }
        set { school1 = value; }
    }
}

 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StudentClass sc = new StudentClass();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = sc1;
    }
```

The Output is as shown below :

[image]

Now in the above picture for Student2 instead of "Name1,Section1,Percentage1,School1" I want to display same as student1.
But I didn't get the required output. So Kindly help me out of this.
I am using C# Winforms in VS2010

And Suggest me how to deny columns resizing i.e., I should not allow user to resize the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DisplayName` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private string name1;
[CategoryAttribute("Student2"), DisplayName("Name")]
public string Name1
{
    get { return name1; }
    set { name1 = value; }
}
```

But note that if the user puts the property grid into A-Z mode, they'll both end up next to each other with no real way to tell them apart.  You may find there's a more appropriate way to represent your data.

Comment: While this would work, I think the real solution here is to break out each "student" into a separate class, then just have student objects in the StudentClass. You can use an expandable object converter to create expanded property objects. Better yet, this could be a collection editor if there are N number of students.

Comment: @Ron Indeed, hence the comment about "a more appropriate way", but we really haven't got enough context to advise, and the question may quickly become too broad.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I got the solution, can you explain your way of solution, so that I can get that way of coding also thanks any way for suggestion.

Comment: @JamesThorpe can you solve my second problem that i mentioned in my question.  And I was unable to use DefaultValue("XYZSchool"). can you help me

Comment: @Gopi I don't know how to disallow column resizing without disabling the entire control, sorry.  If you're having problems with other attributes, you might want to ask a new question with specifics about what isn't working with them